# How to give user input in cronjob script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a run a script in cronjob.
But that script is taking some user input.

How can I handle such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's taking the input from stdin, make another script that will call your script with a pipe or a redirect.

```
#!/bin/sh
/foo/bar/my_command < my_input
```

You can also launch it as a shell command in your crontab:

```
0 * * * * /bin/sh -c "/foo/bar/my_command < my_input"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Modify the script so it does not need user input.
2. Feed the script its required input from a file, via `<`.

Just in case the "expected user input" is, by any chance, a password: **Do not** use option 2. Editing access authentification into a crontab job is various flavors of dangerous.

**PS:** That warning above is also true if you're thinking about `expect`, as suggested by mvp. It is basically the equivalent of writing down your password on a post-it and sticking it to your monitor: Easy, convenient, and not secure at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to simulate manual user input into your script.
This works even if your script does not accept redirection (possible if it needs to enter passwords).

In practice, I found that Perl [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) is much easier to write script for compared to bare `expect`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only confirmation (yes) in your script, the crontab can look like this:

```
0 * * * * /bin/sh -c "yes | /foo/bar/my_command"
```